# Weight paint painting opposite side

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, weight-painting

I am following a doughnut tutorial. The weighted paint is showing on the opposite side of the object I am painting. This is making it difficult as I have to keep going underneath the object to paint the top.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a normal problem, the normals must be flipped, you can check this with the *Display Overlays* panel > *Geometry > Face Orientation*, to fix this press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, it will recalculate outside.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you are following the blenderguru sprinkles tutorial. Make sure in your user preferences (Edit > Preferences) that any weird add-ons are not enabled, and make sure in the modifiers tab (the wrench) that the mirror modifier is not on there. Hope this helps!